# How to call class methods on custom delegate property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, class-method

I have a class "MyCLController" with a property "dataSource" that is data source delegate for "MyCLController" class. "MyCLController" class handles location events and etc, and this class needs several methods for querying and updating several sqlite DB tables. For that reason, I have created "MyCLControlerDataSourceDelegate" protocol that declares, what methods data source delegate class should implement:

```
@protocol MyCLControlerDataSourceDelegate <NSObject>

@required

+ (NSArray *)getAllRegions;
+ (void)saveVisitTimeForRegionID:(NSInteger);
-(void)someInstanceMethod;

@end
```

And here's the datasource delegate property declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyCLControlerDataSourceDelegate> dataSource;
```

After allocing/initing my "MyCLController", I'm linking its dataSource property with an object of type class that implements MyCLControlerDataSourceDelegate protocol.

I would like to design "MyCLController" to be loosely-coupled, so that it doesn't have to know what type of class "dataSource" property is. Everything is nice, when calling instance methods, for example:

```
[self.dataSource someInstanceMethod];
```

But how about calling class methods? I know that class methods should be called [ClassName classMethod] but that would make "MyCLController" less independent.

Comment: Why are they class methods? If you have an instance, which you must do for a delegate, then it seems that all the delegate methods should be instance methods.

Comment: Because, I'm working on a project where I have to implement only my task and not to brake the working conventions of the project. All DB classes and their querying methods are class methods, and those classes are not singletons (except they use DB singleton), their just query DB. And actually I don't need to alloc/init any of those classes. I looking to this need from a perspective of a user, not from the perspective objective-c and their restrictions. Just curious is it possible to do in other way.

Comment: As a coder, I might also be identified as a user who users objective-c and iOS, and looking from that perspective, I feel it would be convenient for me. But if it's not possible I will give up :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the solutions would be to call "class" method on an object. It will get the class name of an object and then we can call it's class method, for example:

```
NSArray *allRegions = [[self.dataSource class] getAllRegions];
```